# How To Deploy Django On Amazon Linux AMI 64 bit

Tags: python, linux, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

It seems the internet doesn't have a clue on how to deploy Django on EC2, since Python2.6 is installed by default. I have found a way to also install Python2.7 together with 2.6, but I don't see a way to lunch Django from Python2.7. My django-admin.py is in /usr/bin/ and somehow, whenever I try to lunch a project, it refers to Python2.6.

How do I install Django in Python2.7? Can I install Pip and then Django from the Python2.7 shell? If then I lunch django-admin.py does Django knows that I want to use Python2.7?

I am a bit confused.

These are the errors I get with Python2.6 ([Deploying Django On Amazon Ec2 Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25962170/deploying-django-on-amazon-ec2-error)), so I guess I now need to find a way to use Django with Python2.7.

Every advice is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You are presumably using the "Amazon Linux" AMI, since the current version of that does supply Python 2.6 by default. According to the [2014.03 release notes](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2014.03-release-notes/), the next version - due this very month - will include Python 2.7. You might want to consider waiting for that to be released.

Alternatively, if you don't know how to install the newer version of Python yourself, you should probably consider using a different distribution. Ubuntu, for example, supplies images for running on EC2, which will include the up-to-date version of Python. See [here](http://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/locator/ec2/).

Comment: Yes, I have just lunched an Ubuntu instance, cause at the moment I just need something running without any problems.